# How to generate random integers in a text box in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How do I randomly generate integer values in a text box for every one second till I click on a button.

I came up with following code (Clicking on Button 1 should generate random integers for every 1 second in textBox1 till Button2 is clicked) and its not working (Output is empty text box).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Timers;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        bool buttonclicked = false;
        System.Timers.Timer myTimer;
        System.Random r = new System.Random();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            while (buttonclicked == false)
            {
                myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
                myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(rnd);
                myTimer.Interval = 1000;
                myTimer.Start();
            }
        }
        public void rnd(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = r.Next(0, 1000).ToString();
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            buttonclicked = true;
            myTimer.Stop();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *while (buttonclicked == false)* that condition will be false the first time, so it will not execute until you press at least once the button 2, try it, press putton two and then button one, it will work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your while(buttonclicked == false) will create an infinite loop once you click the button.You can just do

```
    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            myTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(rnd);
            myTimer.Interval = 1000;
            myTimer.Start();
    }

    private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myTimer.Stop();
    }
```

and you need to make a safe thread call to the textbox by doing :

```
    delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
    private void SetText(string text)
    {
        if (this.textBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = text;
        }
    }
```

And to set the text just use SetText(r.Next(0 ,1000).ToString());

Comment: Thanks Eliran. Its working. As I am beginner in C#, Can you provide some light on whats happening in here `if (this.textBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }`

Comment: The if statement checks if the thread that created the textbox is the same thread that is requesting to change values in it. if it's false then the thread that created the textbox is the same thread that requests to change it, and  therefore we can only use this.textBox1.Text = text, if it's true it will make a safe call to the form and change the text.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like it is because you are using a while loop instead of an if block. Your condition should look like this:

```
if( buttonclicked == false)
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you were right to a loop - but not the timer.

No need to declare the `System.Random` at the class level either - unless you're using it elsewhere.

Using a `for` loop.

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var r = new System.Random();

    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        textBox1.Text = r.Next(0, 1000).ToString();
    }
}
```

Using a `while` loop.

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var r = new System.Random();
    var i = 0;

    while (i < 1000)
    {
        textBox1.Text = r.Next(0, 1000).ToString();
        i++;
    }
}
```

If you really want to add a new number each second, you could use `async` and `await` (to stop UI blocking) and add a `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);`.

Or even `Task` based would be better than a `Timer` (in my opinion).  It's good to understand how Tasks work.

A `Timer` is okay for this scenario - but in real applications they can get messy, especially with multiple timers.

Here is an example of how the above would work using Tasks.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => AddRandomNumbers(uiScheduler));
}

private async Task AddRandomNumbers(TaskScheduler uiScheduler)
{
    var r = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () => textBox1.Text = r.Next(0, 1000).ToString(), 
            CancellationToken.None, 
            TaskCreationOptions.None,
            uiScheduler);

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```